# How to handle errors in bash scripts correctly?

Tags: bash, error-handling

I use `set -e` options on top of my bash scripts to stop executing on any errors. But also I can to use `-e` on echo command like the following:

```
echo -e "Some text".
```

I have two questions:

1. How to handle correctly handle errors in bash scripts?
2. What `-e` options means in `echo` command?

Comment: `-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes`

Comment: `set -e` and `echo -e` have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct" way to handle bash errors depends on the situation and what you want to accomplish.

In some cases, the `if` statement approach that `barmar` describes is the best way to handle a problem.

#### The vagaries of `set -e`

`set -e` will silently stop a script as soon as there is an uncaught error.  It will print no message.  So, if you want to know why or what line caused the script to fail, you will be frustrated.

Further, as documented on [Greg's FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105),  the behavior of `set -e` varies from one bash version to the next and can be quite surprising.

In sum, `set -e` has only limited uses.

#### A `die` function

In other cases, when a command fails, you want the script to exit immediately with a message. In `perl`, the `die` function provides a handy way to do this.  This feature can be emulated in shell with a function:

```
die () {
    echo "ERROR: $*. Aborting." >&2
    exit 1
}
```

A call to `die` can then be easily attached to commands which have to succeed or else the script must be stopped.  For example:

```
cp file1 dir/ || die "Failed to cp file1 to dir."
```

Here, due to the use of bash's OR control operator, `||`, the `die` command is executed *only if* the command which precedes it fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle an error instead of stopping the script when it happens, use `if`:

```
if ! some_command 
then 
    # Do whatever you want here, for instance...
    echo some_command got an error
fi
```

`echo -e` is unrelated. This `-e` option tells the `echo` command to process escape sequences in its arguments. See `man echo` for the list of escape sequences.

Comment: Perhaps also note that `echo -e` is not portable and the OP should probably switch to using `printf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One way of handling error is to use `-e` in your shebang at start of your script and using a `trap` handler for `ERR` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

errHandler () {
   d=$(date '+%D %T :: ')
   echo "$d Error, Exiting..." >&2
   # can do more things like print to a log file etc or some cleanup
   exit 1
}

trap errHandler ERR
```

Now this function `errHandler` will be called **only when an error occurs** in your script.